# mysql trigger than graps value from different tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that adds +1 to my dispense_counter

I have 3 tables:

dispense_table:

```
MasterID - containerID
```

master_table:

```
MasterID - customerID
```

container_table:

```
containerID - customerID - dispense_counter
```

What I'm trying to do is, after each INSERT to my dispense_table i want to add +1 to my dispense_counter

```
WHERE 
master_table.customerID = container_table.customerID AND 
dispense_table.MasterID = master_table.MasterID AND 
dispense_table.containerID = container_table.containerID
```

So everytime i get a dispense in my dispense_table i wanna add +1 in my container_table because it is quite busy table, and takes some times to run the queries for dispenses in a given time.

So

```
CREATE TRIGGER dispense_adding AFTER INSERT ON dispense_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  ????
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns in the new row in `dispense_table` are referenced by the special alias `NEW.*`

```
CREATE TRIGGER dispense_adding AFTER INSERT ON dispense_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE master_table AS m JOIN container_table AS c ON m.customerID = c.customerID
  SET c.dispense_counter = c.dispense_counter + 1
  WHERE m.MasterID = NEW.MasterID AND c.containerID = NEW.containerID;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the NEW.* part made it specially clear for me. Thanks a lot. It works just like i wanted.